# NopCommerce will not mark off messages as sent in message queue and keeps on flooding with E-mails

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I have just installed nopcommerce 1.9 and now configuring it.

Inputed all the correct settings for the SMTP (Host, port etc.) and the test E-mail arrives fine to any address I tested it with.

However should I fill in the contact form or have a new user sign-up the store can't stop sending the same message over and over again to the default store E-mail address or to that of the user. Keeps sending the welcome to the store E-mail for those that signed up or the message body of the contact form etc. To stop it I have to go to message queues and delete the message(s) from there manually, these messages are are flagged as unsent! Even though they have been sent out many times obviously.

So it re-sends everything being sent by the store non stop even though the message went out fine the first time.

Anyone know why it's doing this? Have confirmed I have correct settings for the smtp with my webhost provider, nothing in mail error log of worth.

Thanks...

Comment: where you put all these settings Inputed all the correct settings for the SMTP (Host, port etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run nopCommerce 1.90 under medium trust, please follow the next steps in order fix the issue when customers keep receiving mails:

1. Open \Libraries\Nop.BusinessLogic\Messages\MessageService.cs file
2. Find UpdateQueuedEmail method
3. Replace 
   if (!_context.IsAttached(queuedEmail))
   _context.QueuedEmails.Attach(queuedEmail);

with
if (!_context.IsAttached(queuedEmail))
   _context.QueuedEmails.Attach(queuedEmail);
_context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(queuedEmail, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

1. Recompile the solution

...or simply redownload the latest version [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx) (the version is still 1.90)